# Raspberry Pi crashing while running VGG16

Tags: pi-3, memory

I need to run VGG16 as a convolutional base for feature extraction on some images. I am trying to initialize it on the Raspberry Pi 3B, but the Pi keeps crashing and restarting. I suspect that the Pi doesn't have enough memory for VGG 16, but how should I fix the problem. Here is the VGG16 initialization:

```
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(320, 240, 3))  # 3 = number of channels in RGB pictures
```

I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: What is *VGG16*?

Comment: VGG16 is a type of convolutional neural network used in machine learning.

Comment: There is no machine learning tag in this exchange, so I was unable to specify it. Can you create one?

Comment: `I suspect that the Pi doesn't have enough memory for VGG 16, but how should I fix the problem` buy a pi4 with 4GB - though, first, I'd determine if your memory hypothesis is correct - try monitoring the memory usage of whatever it is you're running to determine if it is indeed the problem

Comment: Look at memory utilization with a program such as htop. I fail to understand why you would want to run such resource-intensive workloads on a such an underpowered machine, but I guess you have your reasons :)

Comment: Hi, htop shows that memory usage is not the problem. Any ideas? The pi just restarts when the code reaches the VGG16 initializations